# Error when overloading insertion (<<) and addition (+)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm learning c++ and this baffling me. I have a `Vector` class with the plus and insertion operators overloaded:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector {
    public:
        Vector(float _x, float _y, float _z) {
            x = _x; y = _y; z = _z;
        }

        float x, y, z;
};

Vector operator+(const Vector &v1, const Vector &v2) {
    return Vector(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z);
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Vector &v) {
    out << "(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << ")";

    return out;
}


int main() {
    Vector i(1, 0, 0);
    Vector j(0, 1, 0);

    std::cout << i;
    /* std::cout << (i + j); */

}
```

When I try to print a `Vector` everything is fine:

```
Vector i(1, 0, 0);
std::cout << i;  // => "(1, 0, 0)"
```

Adding vectors works fine also:

```
Vector i(1, 0, 0);
Vector j(0, 1, 0);
Vector x = i + j;
std::cout << x;  // => "(1, 1, 0)"
```

But if I try to print the sum of two vectors without an intermediary variable I get a **huge** compile error which I really don't understand:

```
Vector i(1, 0, 0);
Vector j(0, 1, 0);
std::cout << (i + j);  // Compile Error

vector.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
vector.cpp:28:15: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘Vector’)
     std::cout << (i + j);
               ^
vector.cpp:17:15: note: candidate: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Vector&) <near match>
 std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Vector &v) {
               ^
vector.cpp:17:15: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
vector.cpp:28:21: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Vector&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Vector’
     std::cout << (i + j);
```

What am I doing wrong? Should this even work?

Comment: I just tried passing the vector to << by value instead of by reference and it works, so I thought: "Aha! perhaps you can't pass the result of an expression by reference for some reason". But then I tried `const Vector &v` and it worked fine so now I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the addition operator isn’t something you can take a non-`const` reference to. Since you’re not modifying `Vector` in `<<`, though, you can and should make it `const`:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Vector &v) {
    out << "(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << ")";

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Well that works, but whats the reason you cannot take a non `const` reference? I would've understood that you can't take references to the results of expressions not assigned to variables but this is weird to me.

Comment: @herrecito: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx might help. A non-`const` reference is a possible lvalue and you can’t make that from something that can only be an rvalue, but a `const` reference is not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not being able to take references at all seemed ok. Only being able to take const references didn't.

Comment: @herrecito: Oh right well, okay. Yeah, refs-to-`const` are a special case. Think about it: otherwise you'd not be able to do much of anything with temporaries without copying them.